# Excel - SUMIFS + INDEX + MATCH with Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the example below, I'm trying to sum any numbers that fit the criteria: Beverage + RTD Coffee for the month of January from the source.

This is the formula that I'm currently trying to use for the above scenario:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX('Grocery Input'!$D8:$BY66,MATCH(1,('Grocery Input'!$D8:$D66=Summary!$D8)*('Grocery Input'!$E8:$E66=Summary!$E8),0),F$6),'Grocery Input'!$D8:$D66,"="&Summary!$D8,'Grocery Input'!$E8:$E66,"="&Summary!$E8)
```

It needs to check both the 'Family' criteria and "Master Category' criteria

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your images are identical.  I think you are missing your source data on the `Grocery Input` sheet.

Comment: @ReyJuna It should be fixed now.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52635640/edit) and provide us with the formula you are currently using?

Comment: Currently your above stated problem seems a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Instead of posting something of this scale that is hard to capture in a few screenshots and a few paragraphs, can you reduce your problem down to a sample size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just eliminate the index match portion of the formulas and use SUMIFS with direct cell references?

For example,

```
=SUMIFS('Grocery Input'!$AD$8:$AD$66,'Grocery Input'!$D$8:$D$66,Summary!$D8,'Grocery Input'!$E$8:$E$66,Summary!$E8)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am stupid and was completely overthinking what functionality was needed for this.